# Angular 9 : The class cannot be created via dependency injection, as it does not have an Angular decorator

Tags: angular

This error is driving me up a wall. I have an authguard service as seen here. No matter what I do the compiler keeps giving me this error

```
'
Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'AuthGuard', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').
```

'

```
   @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private myService: MyService,
        private router: Router)}
```

and I am implementing it here in my app.module

```
providers: [  
    AuthGuard
]
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I clearly have the injectable decorator above the Authguard class but I still get this error. This only happened when I upgraded from Angular 8 to 9.1
Is this a bug of some sort with VS Code or the compiler or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are registering same dependency from 2 places

First is `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. You are registering with root injector with this syntax `{ providedIn: 'root' }`.

Second is below you are registering again, that is the reason for your error.

```
providers: [  
    AuthGuard
]
```

Just remove it from providers array and it will resolve your issue.

Comment: woudn't it be cleaner to leave it in providers[] and edit the @Injectable instead ?

Comment: Its good practice to register it via Injectable decorator. Tree shaking mechanism can drop these if you do not inject it anywhere and that does not happen in case of providers array. You are free to choose as it will work for both cases.